# Directional derivative of a function of three variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm a Mathematica beginner and I'm and struggling with a problem concerning heat flow, not sure how to set it up with three variables. Any help with what I should input into Mathematica will be much appreciated.

> Experiments show that in a temperature field, heat flows in the direction
> of maximum decrease of temperature $T$. Find this direction in general and at the point $(2, -1, 2)$ for $(, , ) = ^2 + ^2 + 4^2$.

Comment: Try taking the gradient and flipping the sign: `-D[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2, {{x, y, z}}] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {2, -1, 2}]` or similarly `-Grad[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2, {x, y, z}] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {2, -1, 2}]`. For directional derivatives there is [`ResourceFunction["DirectionalD"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DirectionalD)

Comment: i tried this and mathematica won't recognize my function having three variables, z is still in blue unlike x and y

Comment: I'm guessing you wrote `-D[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2, {x, y, z}]` which is wrong. You need `{{x,y,z}}` with double braces, or just use `Grad`. Otherwise you need to post what you tried. If you are using a function: `T[x_,y_,z_]:=x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2;  -Grad[T[x,y,z],{x,y,z}]`

Answer (score 3):

Here we use Mathematica to verify that the `-Grad` satisfy the maximum decrease.

the `result1` according to the definition of derivative along a vector `v`.

Now it is equal to `result2` or `result3` means that the direction derivative is equal to $\nabla T\bullet v$, the projection of the gradient of $T$ to $v$.

After that, we use `Maximize` to find the direction `v` which attain the maximum decrease of temperature T,and it is just equal to the normalize of `-Grad`.

```
Clear[T,p, p0, v];
T[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2;
p = {x, y, z};
p0 = {x0, y0, z0};
v = {α, β, γ};
result1 = 
  Limit[(T[Sequence @@ (p0 + t*v)] - T[Sequence @@ p0])/t, t -> 0, 
   Direction -> "FromAbove"];
result2 = Grad[T[Sequence @@ p], p].v /. Thread[p -> p0];
result3 = D[T[Sequence @@ p], {p}].v /. Thread[p -> p0];
result1 == result2 == result3
v /. Last@Maximize[{-result1, Total[v^2] == 1^2}, v] /. 
  Thread[p0 -> {2, -1, 2}] // Simplify
```

> `True`

> `{-(2/Sqrt[69]), 1/Sqrt[69], -(8/Sqrt[69])}`

Comment: thank you this was very helpful